# How does adding にする to よう change its meaning?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I know that ようにする means ***to be sure to do something***, but how does it get this meaning from adding にする to よう (which means ***appear to be/similar to***)？

In other words, how does:

> よう + にする = to be sure to do something

What is よう doing in ようにする?

Comment: Do you also have trouble with ようになる?

Comment: Yes I do! @aguijonazo I can understand the meaning but not what よう is doing there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Native speakers don’t necessarily see the ように in ようになる or ようにする as the same thing as the ように in, say, ように見える, which describes what your perception or impression is like.

However, they are certainly related. If you choose to, you could understand the ように in ようになる and ようにする as describing what the result of a change would be **like**.

Consider the following sentence as an example.

> 新聞が読めるようになる。
> You will be able to read newspapers.

新聞が読める describes the target state you think the person will be in when the change in question has happened. The connection with the other usage may be clearer when ように is used with a noun.

> 学者のようになる。
> You will be like a scholar.

This practically means the same as the following with みたい.

> 学者みたいになる。

ように in this sense is not usually used with an adjective. There is a better way to say the same thing.

> 賢くなる。
> You will be smart.

> 綺麗になる。
> You will be beautiful.

When ように is used with a verb, that verb normally refers to a state, not a one-time action or change. In the first example, a potential form is used to describe a state where you have the ability to do something. When a dictionary form is used, it is still understood as referring to a state, a habitual state to be more precise.

> 新聞を読むようになる。
> You will get into the habit of reading newspapers.

Note that ように cannot be replaced with みたいに in these examples with a verb.

ようにする works in the same way except you are the one who actively causes the change.

> 新聞を読むようにする。
> I will make it a habit to read newspapers.

The verbal phrase before ように still describes what the intended target state is like.

You can also use a more concrete verb instead of する.

> 新聞が読めるように毎日勉強する。
> I will study everyday so that I will be able to read newspapers.

This may make it easer to understand that ように describes what the intended target state is like because of the way it is translated into English. It now neatly corresponds to “so that.”

On the other hand, it becomes syntactically similar to a sentence like this.

> 貪るように毎日勉強する。
> He studies everyday as if to “devour” (books).

In this sentence, ように is used to describe how something is done as you perceive it, just like the ように in ように見える. We know that because it is hard to interpret 貪る as describing a habitual state, and it is much more normal to understand it as referring to an action to which the way he studies is likened. In short, you need context to determine in which meaning ように is used.

Comment: If ように marks the result of a change, why do you use "like"? E.g. "You will be like a scholar." sounds to me like you'll be a scholar in form, not in essence. Scholar on the outside, not on the inside.

Comment: @x-yuri - I added that example as a bridge to connect the よう in `[V present plain form]-ようになる／する` with the よう the OP apparently understood as “like.” The sentence means when the change has happened, the person will be **like** a scholar (in one way or another). If you want to say they will be a scholar, you should say 学者になる. The point I wanted to make was that although よう is a necessary part of the construct with a verb, it could still be understood as “like” as in the example with a noun. If the result of the change can be expressed with a simple noun phrase, it takes the form of `[N]-になる`.

Comment: So basically ように can play either purely grammatical role, or introduce some sort of vagueness (to appear, in one way or another). And although your usage of "like" seems valid to me, it may sound a bit ambiguous in purely grammatical cases. E.g. `The verbal phrase before ように still describes what the intended target state is like.` I'd say "describes the intended target state." Although it makes sense to use the version with "like" here, it may suggest that ように in the example is used to introduce some sort of vagueness (not just for a grammatical purpose)...

Comment: ...Then, the example with a scholar apparently needs "like." But soon you say, `ように in this sense is not usually used with an adjective. There is a better way to say the same thing. 賢くなる。` But the "better way" apparently lacks the connotation of vagueness, as opposed to the previous example. That is, the "better way" is not the "same thing." At least that's my understanding.

Comment: @x-yuri - 賢いです and 綺麗です make sense as response to a question asking what something is **like**. 学者です doesn't.