# '～ような'　to modify nouns after adjectives

Tags: grammar, meaning, video-games

Konnichi wa ! I got this sentence from an 岩田【いわた】聡【さとる】 speech concerning Nintendo.

> 私【わたし】たちは、これからもきっと、非常識【ひじょうしき】と言【い】われるような提案【ていあん】をするでしょう。それが任天堂【にんてんどう】と言【い】う会社【かいしゃ】のありようだと、私【わたし】は思【おも】っております。

https://www.nintendo.co.jp/ir/events/081031/09.html

In the part 「非常識【ひじょうしき】と言【い】われるような提案【ていあん】をするでしょう」, does 「ような」 modify 非常識【ひじょうしき】 to make it into an adjective? Or does 「ような」 have another meaning?

For me, it translates as: *"we will for sure (from now on) make ideas that seem to be called absurd"*

Comment: Should be a duplicate of [Meaning of ような when it is not decribing likeness/appearance](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94642/45489)

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct. Adding ”ような” back to ”非常識” is similar to adding ”seem to be called” ahead to ”absurd”.